# Consequences of Warming Liquid Malt Extract?

Tags: extract, malt

If I get a large internet delivery from NB of 4 extracts, I put everything into the fridge, hops and malt included.

On brew day, If I were to just take the liquid malt out of the fridge and attempt to pour it into my kettle, it would take forever because the viscosity of the liquid at that point is so bad.

What I do instead is get a pot and run hot water into it continuously and put my liquid malt bottles inside of this to moderate the viscosity.

I am wondering if heating the liquid malt extract like this prior to the boil had any type of consequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I say that it's unnecessary - the malt extract does not need to go into the fridge, since it's sterile from the producer. Also nothing can grow in the malt extract due to the high sugar content, so I'd say the chilling and reheating is just creating extra work.

Simply leave the malt extract at room temperature and pour into the pot. If you want to decrease the viscosity, then letting the extract stand in some warm water may help, but this is often unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no consequences to this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no fault with warming the extract. Some of the companies recommend it as it makes pouring the liquid easier.

Good Idea: Placing the can in a basin of hot water
Bad Idea: Heating the can on a stovetop or suchlike may cause the can to burst.

What I do is warm the can in hot water in the basin while I wait for my brewing water to come to a boil. I remove the labeling and glue, etc. When the brewing water has reached boiling point I remove the pot from heat and then take the can out of the water in the basin. Open can and pour the liquid into the pot. When the bulk has been poured out I use tongs to lower the can into the brewing water so that the still near boiling water flows into the can. I swirl the liquid inside the can, pour out and repeat until the can is empty. Discard can. Last two steps: Mix the extract well into the water and then return to heat source.

Side note: This method adds all the extract at the start of the boil. Late extract edition also exists.